# Suspicious guest user activity and keyboard setting changes

Tags: settings, keyboard, nexus-4, logging, multi-user

A guest user is occasionally created on my phone and I don't know why. It consumes some mobile data, as indicated by Android's data usage report.

Another suspicious thing is that my keyboard's languages are regularly disabled, only leaving the default one.

How can I log this activity, so that the next time any of this happens, I can know what app is causing it ?